# Spherical / Custom projection at code level

Tags: python

This question is identical to [Custom nonlinear distortion lens](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7601/custom-nonlinear-distortion-lens)

With one difference: I'm only interested in a solution at the code level. Because that gives a fine-grained control.

How does one go about doing this?

Here is the setup:

[image]

For each square on that grid, a ray is shot out through each corner, returning a colour.  The four corners are averaged, and the resultant colour is given to that pixel. (if there is more than a certain maximum allowed amount of variation between the 4 values, the square is cut up into 4 little squares, and so on, recursively)

That's the standard projection model I'm familiar with.

What I want to do is manually fire out rays myself.

I'm guessing that somewhere low down in the C code level, there is some routine that performs this operation.

But where? Can someone direct me? I would be very daunted to have to hunt it down myself through the Blender source code.

And can this be done in Python? Is there some command for firing a ray and retrieving the colour? If this is the case then I could in theory write my own ray projector, and save the resulting 2D RGB array to file.

Comment: It seems someone has [implemented a patch](https://developer.blender.org/T35428) which allows you to define your own distortion with a map.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it can be down in Python. But definitely possible in C.

Blender Cycles support non-planar lenses ala fisheye. You can find the user documentation for it on the [wiki.](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Camera)

A walkthrough (and patch) from the developer who implemented this feature can be found on [Dalai Felinto](http://www.dalaifelinto.com/?p=399)'s website.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it's possible with python, but here's somewhere to start:
[1](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/RenderEngineAPI),[2](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html).  As a side note, blender's model is to shoot out one ray per square, unless anti-aliasing is enabled under the render panel. With antialising, it uses the specified amount of samples and mixing algorithm.