# Cycles generates distorted depth

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, camera, point-clouds, matrix

The depth map generated by the Cycles rendering engine seems to have (radial) distortion, while the Blender renderer does not.

However, I could not find anywhere information on the internal camera model used by the Cycles engine, leading to this very post.

### Specifics

With the Blender default scene and default parameters, I use a Viewer node connected to the Z Render layer and a python script to read the generated depth map, compute 3D point coordinates and export as OBJ.

The node graph is very simple:

[image]

The export python code too:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

print("exporting depth pointcloud to OBJ...")

scale = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100

pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
img = np.array(pixels[:]).reshape(int(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y * scale), int(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x * scale),-1)

camdata = bpy.data.objects["Camera"].data

sensor_height = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y / bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x * camdata.sensor_width

f = open("/tmp/pointcloud_blender.obj","w")

for u in range(0, img.shape[1]):
    for v in range(0, img.shape[0]):

        d = img[v, u][0]

        if d > 100.0:
            continue

        x = d * (0.5 - float(u) / float(img.shape[1])) * camdata.sensor_width / camdata.lens;
        y = d * (0.5 - float(v) / float(img.shape[0])) * sensor_height / camdata.lens;
        z = d;

        f.write("v " + str(x) + " " + str(y) + " " + str(z) + "\n")

f.close()

print("DONE")
```

When rendering with the Blender internal engine, the generated point cloud looks like the square as it should (white), but the Cycles rendering engine gives a distorted point cloud (red):

[image]

When looking at the depth maps, one can clearly see a radial distortion (Blender render vs Cycles render, exported with File Output node):

[image]

This is a cut of the depth maps (blue, green) and difference image (red) at row 240:

[image]

(the two depth maps being different are not really the problem here, as long as I have the correct unprojection model)

### Research

I looked in [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/render/cycles/camera.html), in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38460) stating that the Blender camera has no distortion coefficients, on [this blog](https://www.rojtberg.net/1601/from-blender-to-opencv-camera-and-back/) that is the correct model I use for the Blender camera.

I also studied the [code for Cycles](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/C/repository/master/) (`src/render/camera.cpp`, `src/util/util_projection.h`, `src/util/util_transform.h`) but could not find any trace of radial distortion.

### Question

Does anybody have **an idea of the internal camera model used by the Cycles rendering engine** ? Or how to compute correct camera intrinsic parameters ?
I guess the lens has distortion, but I could not find parameters or even code running this.

I need to be able to use the point cloud from the depth maps from different views, but with distortion they are not usable.

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to BSE. This is the best first post I have seen one this site. Very well done, the formatting, layout, sources, and research all excellent. I wish everybody put as much effort into their posts. Glad you found the answer (and then shared it here!), sorry we could not help.

Comment: This completely slipped under my radar, great post, welcome to the community!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to the [Blender dev forum](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-generates-distorted-depth/5409/2), I figured it out.

The Cycles camera is a pinhole model that "uses the distance between a given point and the pinhole as its Z depth".
So we cannot apply the depth to points on the camera plane, but rather points that lie on the unit sphere, hence normalized.

Here is the correct formula to unproject a camera pixel into a 3D point :

```
    import math

    # coordinates on camera plane
    x = (0.5 - float(u) / float(img.shape[1])) * camdata.sensor_width / camdata.lens;
    y = (0.5 - float(v) / float(img.shape[0])) * sensor_height / camdata.lens;
    z = 1.0;

    norm = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)

    # normalize = project point on unit sphere, then apply depth
    x = d * x / norm
    y = d * y / norm
    z = d * z / norm
```

The relevant code is in [kernel_camera.h](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/C/browse/master/src/kernel/kernel_camera.h$42)