# Different Z Pass values given by Eevee and Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

**Problem**

I've been reconstructing point clouds from blender's Z-pass outputs; saving to .exr to capture the full detail. I've noticed that when I use the EEVEE engine flat surfaces are reconstructed flat - but using cycles the same captured Z pass includes radial distortion even when accounting for the camera intrinsics.

**Linked Images**

[Cycles Z pass to point cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOZ3U.png) [Eevee Z pass to point cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vsNq.png)

At this point I'd be assuming that Eevee is taking Z distance from the camera, whereas Cycles is calculating the length of the path before intersection, but I can't find any confirmation of these different behaviours.

Comment: Upon further searching, this post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130970/cycles-generates-distorted-depth suggests that this is the result of the pinhole camera model used by the cycles renderer. As is pointed out; it's confusing that the two rendering methods have a different camera model; and this has persisted with the Introduction of Eevee

Comment: This question may be duplicate of the previous, although the rendering engines being compared are different, the behaviour is the same.